# Potentially polymorphic call when calling a method of undeclared interface

Tags: php, type-hinting, php-8

Suppose I have a class C1 that implements two interfaces (I1, I2) in PHP 8.

I inject that class C1 in the constructor of another class C2 typehinting it with one of the interfaces (I1).

Now, when I call a method of I2 interface Sonarlint complains with message:

> Potentially polymorphic call.

Can I get rid of this messages somehow?

Comment: As an aside, there has been a move away from the term "type hint" in the context of PHP, because they don't just "hint" at types, they *enforce* them. The manual now calls them ["type declarations"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make this a bit more concrete:

```
interface I1 {
   public function one();
}

class C2 {
   public function __construct( I1 $injected ) {
       $injected->one();
       $injected->two();
   }
}
```

Note that I haven't shown interface `I2` or class `C1` here, because there's nothing in class `C2` that says they're relevant.

What the tool is telling you is that *looking just at the definition of class `C2`*, there is no way to know that `$injected->two()` is a valid method call - the only method we know for sure `$injected` has is `one()`, because we know it implements interface `I1`.

The fact that *in practice* you always pass an object that has more methods, and implements an additional interface, is not documented in class `C2` at all.

The way to fix that is to add more information to `C2`, to say that the passed object must implement *both* `I1` *and* `I2`:

```
interface I1 {
   public function one();
}
interface I2 {
   public function two();
}

class C2 {
   public function __construct( I1&I2 $injected ) {
       // Both calls are guaranteed to be valid
       $injected->one();
       $injected->two();
   }
}

class C1 implements I1, I2 {
   public function one() { ... }
   public function two() { ... }
}
new C2( new C1 ); // passes the check, because it implements both interfaces
```

This syntax with an `&` in the type (`I1&I2`) is known as an "intersection type", as opposed to the more common "union type" syntax, e.g. `I1|I2` would mean "must implement at least one of `I2` and `I2`".

Intersection types were added in PHP 8.1. If you need your code to work on older versions, it's a little bit trickier, but can be achieved by introducing a new interface that inherits both existing interfaces. The difference is that class `C2` must implement this new interface explicitly for the check to pass:

```
interface I1 {
   public function one();
}
interface I2 {
   public function two();
}
interface I1and2 extends I1, I2 {}

class C2 {
   public function __construct( I1and2 $injected ) {
       // Both calls are guaranteed to be valid
       $injected->one();
       $injected->two();
   }
}

class C1 implements I1and2 {
   public function one() { ... }
   public function two() { ... }
}
new C2( new C1 ); // passes the check
```

Alternatively, if your two interfaces actually represent two separate abilities that class `C2` happens to cover, but *could* be covered by separate objects, you can just have two parameters, each defining one required interface:

```
interface I1 {
   public function one();
}
interface I2 {
   public function two();
}

class C2 {
   public function __construct( I1 $injected1, I2 $injected2 ) {
       // Valid call on any I1 instance
       $injected1->one();
       // Valid call on any I2 instance
       $injected2->two();
   }
}

class C1 implements I1, I2 {
   public function one() { ... }
   public function two() { ... }
}
$something = new C1;
new C2( $something, $something ); // passes both checks
```

Remember in each case that the point of using interfaces in the first place is to document the *invariant properties* of the code, rather than the implementation you happen to have at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. With PHP 8.0 type-hinting the injection of C1 in the constructor of C2 with the union type (I1|I2) worked as well.

Comment: @framontb A union type *should not* be enough here - you can still pass an object that only implements interface `I1`, and all the calls to methods from `I2` will fail. The minimum requirement is that the object implements *both* interfaces, not at least one of them.